# What handles the keyboard NumLock LED?

Tags: keyboard, numlock

I want to find confirmation that the keyboard on a PC type computer controls the NUM_LOCK LED locally or if the Computer System software sends commands to the keyboard to manage this LED based upon it seeing scan codes from the <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> key.

I ask this because I was recently doing some experimentation with a separate USB Numerical Keypad and found that when its <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> button is pushed there is no NUM_LOCK scan code sent to the computer at that time although its NUM_LOCK LED comes on. Using an online browser based keyboard test I see that this weird keypad, when in the NumLock mode will send the following for each of the other key pad keys:: Numlock Down Scan Code - Number Button Down Scan Code - Number Button Up Scan Code - Numlock Up Scan Code.

In the same keyboard test my regular keyboard sends a NumLock Down and then NumLock Up scan codes as the <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> button is pressed and released.

Why would this USB Keypad work differently that the regular keyboard?

Comment: The LED functionality likely is entirely internal to the PCB for the keyboard itself

Comment: it might be as the separate numpad keyboards are created to extend shortened keyboards as usually found on laptops and many of those have the numbers overlapping on the right hand side on top of the letters (usually you can turn them on with fn+numlock) and the from you described key sequences will ensure that the laptop keyboard will type only letters... just a thought, didnt google it, have no evidence, ....

Comment: When I remap so that CapsLock sends <ctrl>, <ctrl> sends <alt>, and <alat> sends CapsLock, the CapsLock LED responds to the remapped key, not its physical key. That would lead me to believe that built-in hardware is responding to OS receiving ScanCode. But I think your external keypad may function differently.

Comment: The num/scroll/capslock can be set via software. You can find an example here [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Y4J6A4F0TU)

Answer (score 2):

PC host is responsible for sending LED state to keyboard and keyboard itself is responsible for preserving last set LED state. In Windows LED state is updated by keyboard driver to be in sync with [VK_CAPITAL/VK_NUMLOCK/VK_SCROLL/VK_KANA virtual-key codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) state of the current thread.

Modern keyboards are working via [Device Class Definition for HID 1.11](https://www.usb.org/hid) (USB HID spec). Bluetooth keyboards are using this spec too under the hood.

According to the **Appendix C: Keyboard Implementation** of the spec:

Synchronization between LED states and CAPS LOCK, NUM LOCK, SCROLL LOCK, COMPOSE, and KANA events **is maintained by the host** and NOT the keyboard. If using the keyboard descriptor in Appendix B, LED states are set by sending a 5-bit absolute report to the keyboard via a Set_Report(Output) request.

According to **B.1 Protocol 1 (Keyboard)** of **Appendix B: Boot Interface Descriptors"**:

The following table represents the keyboard output report (1 byte).

| Bit | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | NUM LOCK |
| 1 | CAPS LOCK |
| 2 | SCROLL LOCK |
| 3 | COMPOSE |
| 4 | KANA |
| 5 to 7 | CONSTANT |

Note. The LEDs are absolute output items. This means that the state of each LED must be included in output reports (0 = off, 1 = on). Relative items would permit reports that affect only selected controls (0 = no change, 1 = change).