# Is it possible to remap laptop LED indicator lights to another function? ie. trackpad-lock to numlock?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, windows-11, numlock, indicator

Is there a way to remap any of the keyboard indicator LEDs on a laptop to another function?

My HP Victus 15-fa1093dx has indicator LED's for TrackPad-Lock, CapsLock, Speaker Mute, and Power, but not NumLock. The number-pad contains the only Home/End/PgUP/PgDown keys, which has me reaching for the NumLock-key more than ever. The lack of a numLock status light is annoying and I would happily re-map any of the 4 available LEDs, preferably 'track-pad lock' which I will likely never use.

I saw no options in the BIOS. HP Support suggested this question was 'out of scope' but suggested I call another premium(paid) support line they have.

System:

- Windows 11 Home
- Intel I5-13420H

[edit]
The answer to this question [What handles the keyboard NumLock LED?](https://superuser.com/questions/1545130/what-handles-the-keyboard-numlock-led) leads me to believe controlling/remapping these lights is possible, but doesn't give me an idea of how I would do it.

Comment: HP Support doesn’t provide premium support services. Careful of call centers that claim they are HP when they actually are not.

Comment: What OS are you running on this laptop?

Comment: Thank you for the warning! In this case I was referred to https://www.hp.com/us-en/services/consumer/smartfriend-overview.html which appears real but I'm not spending money on it. It is true real call-centers have had problems with agent-fraud in the work-from-home era. The same agents can handle email/chat/phone so this applies to all channels.

Comment: @u1686_grawity Windows 11 Home